# Return to dbt version 19.1

Tags: homebrew, dbt

I am not sure how badly I have hosed this. I updated dbt to v20 globally too soon. I did uninstall v20. I need to return the project to version 19.1. I am running into errors doing this. As background I am running a virtual. I am on macos.
These two commands work as expected:
`brew tap dbt-labs/dbt`
`brew unlink dbt`

Then I run `brew install dbt-labs/dbt/dbt@0.19.1`

I get (I expect this) `Warning: dbt-labs/dbt/dbt@0.19.1 0.19.1_1 is already installed, it's just not linked. To link this version, run: brew link dbt@0.19.1`

Then I run `brew link dbt@0.19.1` or `brew link dbt-labs/dbt/dbt@0.19.1` and I get:

```
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps: 
       * dbt-labs/dbt/dbt@0.12.2-rc1
       * fishtown-analytics/dbt/dbt@0.12.2-rc1

Please use the fully-qualified name (e.g. dbt-labs/dbt/dbt@0.12.2-rc1) to refer to the formula.
```

So I try `brew link dbt-labs/dbt/dbt@0.12.2-rc1`

Disclosure...I code dbt modules but I do not get too far into the installation since I rarely need to do it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I’m no help here as I’m no brew expert, buy I’d recommend trying pip instead!

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this issue in the dbt-labs/dbt repo](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/issues/3860) helpful.

TL;DR:

You may be running into issues due to the repo name change. It could help to do a full re-install, i.e.:

```
brew untap fishtown-analytics/dbt --force
brew tap dbt-labs/dbt
brew install dbt@x.y.z
```

You can then follow the instructions [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/installation#installing-different-versions-with-homebrew) as normal for managing several versions with homebrew.

Comment: That got me much further. Not sure if this should be a new ticket. If I run `dbt --version` 
I get 

`File "/Users/barbara/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/bz2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'`
I have tried uninstalling pyenv, home brew, the libraries, etc. No love.